# How to connect microservice to SQS/SNS

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-sqs, microservices

I have a java microservice that runs in a Docker container in a Ec2 instance . 
It has to get notified when a file is dropped in a S3 bucker. We have a SNS and SQS that is connected to the S3 bucket. How can i connect the microserice to the SNS/SQS ? If there is a better way to get the java microservice get notified when the files is dropped into S3 bucket please let me know ?

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) is pretty good.
You can either:

- write an HTTP endpoint that SNS can post to (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html)
  or
- subscribe to an SQS topic (see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonSimpleQueueService/SimpleQueueServiceSample.java).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one use case of AWS Lambda:

> As an event-driven compute service where AWS Lambda runs your code in
>   response to events, such as changes to data in an Amazon S3 bucket or
>   an Amazon DynamoDB table.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html

Since it runs your code, you are free to write something that places a request to a microservice.